# How to put different values under the same parameter label

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table that looks similar to the example below when selecting distinct. The format is MainFolder-SubFolder1-SubFolder2

| Folder |
| --- |
| A |
| A-B |
| A-B-C |
| B-C |
| B-D-E |

I want to create a drop down parameter where the options would be A or B. If I select A, then the table will show A, A-B, and A-B-C. Ideally I would like to create multiple parameter so users are able to select what main folder they want to look at as well as the subfolders.

I have tried creating a dataset with the following query
`SELECT DISTINCT Folder, CASE  WHEN Folder LIKE 'A%' THEN 'A'  WHEN Folder LIKE 'B%' THEN 'B'  END AS MainFolder` Which gives the table below

| Folder | MainFolder |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A-B | A |
| A-B-C | A |
| B-C | B |
| B-D-E | B |

I then create a parameter where the available values are from the dataset. The value field is Folder and label field is MainFolder. I want it so that when I run the report the parameter only shows A or B, but the table will show the full folder details. However what I get from the drop down parameter is A, A, A, B, B.

Comment: So what is your question? What is stopping you achieving what you want?

Comment: I have edited my question to give more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your issue but can you not just create dataset for the parameter values that look something like this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Folder, 1) AS MainFolder FROM myTable
```

Then you main dataset query would be something like ...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Left(Folder,1) = @pMainFolder
```

... where `pMainFolder` is the name of your parameter

or if pMainFolder was multi-values you could do

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Left(Folder,1) IN(@pMainFolder)
```

**UPDATE ** after OP additional info.

Assuming all the folders have some form of delimiter (the `-` in your example) you can substitute this

```
Left(Folder,1)
```

with

```
LEFT(Folder, CHARINDEX('-', Folder)-1)
```

in the previous examples I posted.

CharIndex gives us the position of the first `-` in the `Folder` column. So in "Admin-south" this would be position 6, we then subtract 1 giving us 5 and use that in the `LEFT` function so we only get back the first 5 leftmost characters, in this example "Admin"

Comment: Yes this does exactly what I wanted! Thank you! However the folder names are not literally A, B, etc. They are more like Admin-west, Admin-south, Andon, Andon-east etc. So Left(Folder,1) is putting both Admin and Andon under A. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `LIKE` can use indexes, `LEFT()` cannot, so you'd want `WHERE Folder LIKE @pMainFolder + '%'`

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue please mark it as accepted (The check mark below the vote up/down buttons to the left of the answer)